# Create an email reference thread id for a custom object

Tags: email, formula

trying to create an email reference thread id for a custom object. I found the following field formula on the web.

FORMULA

```
ref:"&LEFT( $Organization.Id , 4)&"0"&RIGHT( $Organization.Id , 4)&"."&LEFT(Id , 4)&"0"&RIGHT(Id , 5)&":ref
```

However, when I tried to create the formula field on the custom object, I get the following error message...

> "Error: Syntax error. Missing '='".

I'm not sure what that error message means or how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this as the formula

```
"[ref:_" & LEFT($Organization.Id,5) & SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT($Organization.Id,11), "0", "" ) & "._" & LEFT(Id,5) & SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(Id,11), "0", "" ) & ":ref]"
```

Comment: When I try to validate the syntax I get the same error message with the following text highlighted "" & LEFT($Organization.Id,5) & SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT($Organization.Id,11), "" and when I add a "=" after the ref:_, I get the following error message "Error: Syntax error. Missing ']'" and the first "0" referenced is highlighted. Again, kinda at a lost here.  BTW, thanks for your response

Comment: Here is what I have, which works - https://www.dropbox.com/s/mhctbhitmnam8yz/CaseRef.png?dl=0  - does your setup look different?